# Exponential differential operator

Tags: differential-operators

Consider the operator $D= e^{ax \frac{d}{dx}}$ operating on an infinitely differentiable function $f(x)$.

My approach:
$$
Df(x)= f(x) + ax \frac{df(x)}{dx} + (ax)^2\frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2} + \cdots =f(x+ax)
$$
But this does not seem to be the answer. Can anyone tell me if and where did I go wrong?

Comment: This is the dilation operator, not translation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It appears that the OP interpreted the operator $e^{\left((ax)\frac{d}{dx}\right)}$ on $f(x)$ incorrectly to mean $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(ax)^n}{n!}\frac{d^nf(x)}{dx^n}$.
>
> This misinterpretation in the OP is due to applying incorrectly successive applications of the operator $ax\frac{d}{dx}$.  One application reveals $ \left((ax)\frac{d}{dx}\right)f(x)=axf'(x)$.  A subsequent application yields
>
> $$\begin{align}
> \left((ax)\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2 f(x)&=\left((ax)\frac{d}{dx}\right)\left(axf'(x)\right)\\\\
> &=(ax)^2f''(x)+a^2xf'(x)\\\\
> &\ne (ax)^2f''(x)
> \end{align}$$
>
> We will show in the following that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(ax)^n}{n!}\frac{d^nf(x)}{dx^n}=f(ax+a)$ while $e^{\left((ax)\frac{d}{dx}\right)}=f(e^a x)$.

---

We begin by analyzing the operator $e^{a\frac{d}{dx}}$ on $C^\infty$ as defined by

$$\left(e^{a\frac{d}{dx}}\right)\{f(x)\}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}a^n\tag1$$

Note that the Taylor series of $f(x+a)$ around $x$ can be written

$$f(x+a)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}a^n\tag2$$

Comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$ reveals

$$\left(e^{a\frac{d}{dx}}\right)\{f(x)\}=f(x+a)$$

---

Next, we transform the operator $x\frac{d}{dx}$ by enforcing the substitution $x=e^y$.  Then, denoting $f(x)=f(e^y)=g(y)$, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\left(ax\frac{d}{dx}\right) f(x)&= \left(ae^y\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d}{dy}\right) f(e^y)\\\\
&=\left(ae^ye^{-y}\frac{d}{dy}\right) f(e^y)\\\\
&=\left(a\frac{d}{dy}\right) g(y)\tag3
\end{align}$$

---

Finally, using $(2)$ and $(3)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\left(e^{(ax)\frac{d}{dx}}\right) f(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n!}\left(\left(ax\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n \right)f(x)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{g^{(n)}(y)}{n!}a^n\\\\
&=g(y+a)\\\\
&=f(e^{y+a})\\\\
&=f(e^ae^y)\\\\
&=f(e^ax)
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Oh, yes. Now i see my mistake. Thanks and there is a mistake in the 7th line where there should be a '+' in place of a '=".

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And thank you for catching the typographical error. I've edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

**Sketch:** Define
\begin{align}
u(t, x) = \exp\left(tx\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)f(x)
\end{align}
then we see that $u$ solves
\begin{align}
\partial_t u - x \partial_x u =0, \ \ \text{ with }\ \ u(0, x) = f(x).
\end{align}
By the method of characteristics, we see that
\begin{align}
u(t, x) = f(xe^{t})
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\exp\left( ax\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right) f = u(a, x) = f(xe^a).
\end{align}

Comment: @MarkViola $\exp(tL)$ is the semigroup for $u_t=Lu$ unless I made some error somewhere.

Comment: Consider f(x)=exp(x) . Then expanding the operator in the exponential series, I am getting Df(x)= exp(x+ax)= f(x+ax) which is not equal to f(xe^a). Is there something wrong in my approach of expanding the operator in the exponential series?

Answer (score 3):

Remember that
$$
e^x = 1 +x +\frac{1}{2!} x^2 + \cdots +\frac{1}{n!} x^n + \cdots
$$
Hence,
$$
\exp(ax \partial_x) f = f +ax\partial_xf +\frac{1}{2}ax\partial_x(ax\partial_x f)+\cdots
$$
Let $x=e^y$ so that $x\partial_x f(x) = \partial_y f(e^y)$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
\exp(ax \partial_x)f &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} (\partial_y^n f(e^y)) a^n \\
&= f(e^{y+a}) \\
&= f(xe^a)
\end{align}

Comment: Yes. I expanding the operator the same way in my approach.